# __getattr__ special method

Tags: attributes, python-3.6, getattr

Why does hasattr() return boolean True below? 'bar' attribute
is not set anywhere in the code. Thanks

```
class AttrClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        pass


data = AttrClass()
print('Current __dict__:  ', data.__dict__)
print('Does bar exists?:  ', hasattr(data, 'bar'))
```

Output:

```
Current __dict__:   {}
Does bar exists?:   True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding the `__getattr__` method and making it always return `None` (since a function that does not explicitly return a value returns `None` implicitly), instances of `AttrClass` would now return `True` for any given name passed to the `hasattr` function simply because the overridden `__getattr__` method does not raise an `AttributeError` exception, and `hasattr` only returns false when it gets an `AttributeError` exception when calling the `__getattr__` the method.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) for details.